# Find all degree solutions in the interval 0° ≤ θ < 360°

Tags: trigonometry

Need help with a math problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Find all degree solutions in the interval $0° ≤ θ < 360°$. If rounding is necessary, round to the nearest tenth of a degree. Use your graphing calculator to verify the solution graphically. (Enter your answers as a comma-separated list.)

$5\sin^2 θ − 6 \cos 2θ = 0$

I used the following double angle formula to make the entire equation sin:

$1-2\sin^2θ=0$

---

$5\sin^2 θ-6(1-2\sin^2θ)=0$

$5\sin^2θ+12\sin^2θ-6=0$

$17\sin^2θ-6=0$

$17\sin^2θ=6$

$\sin^2θ=6/17$

$\sinθ=\pm \sqrt{6/17}$

After taking the inverse of $\sin$ I got

$θ = 36.5°, 130.3°$

Comment: Your calculations are correct.

Comment: You will get 2 solutions for $\sqrt{6/17}$ and 2 more solutions for $-\sqrt{6/17}$.

Comment: Correct except Two things 1) $1-2 \sin^2 \theta= \cos 2 \theta$ instead; and 2) See @AlexZom ‘s comment.

Answer (score 1):

you could also do $$0 = 5 \sin^2 t - 6 \cos 2t =\frac 52\left(1-\cos 2t\right) - 6\cos 2t \to \cos 2t = \frac 5{17}  $$

solutions are $$2t = \pm \cos^{-1}\left(\frac5{17}\right) + 360^\circ k =\pm 72.8953^\circ+360^\circ  k$$ that is $$t = 36.4476, 143.552^\circ, 216.447^\circ,323.552^\circ $$